# What is the probability that at the throw of a dice the number one comes up before an even number?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

THinking about solving like this: ${1\over6}+ ({2\over 6})({1\over 6})+({2\over 6})^2({1\over6})+ \dots$ because the plausible cases would be {1}{(3 or 5),1}{(3 or 5)(3 or 5),1} and so on... Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the die shows $3$ or $5$ you will throw it again.
You keep doing this until some other number comes up, and that's your last throw.

If the last throw is a $1$, the $1$ occurred before any even number.
Otherwise an even number occurred first.

So what is the chance that the last throw is $1$, and what does that tell you
about the prior probability (before you start throwing the die)
that a $1$ will come up before an even number?

Comment: im guessing what I did is correct ..?

Comment: Yes, your work is correct so far.